# iAd adBannerView.adType.rawValue values?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, iad

Another quick question on IOS Swift iAd

I came across the [adType.rawValue] element and wonder has anybody got a detail information of what values did this element carry ?

adBannerView.adType.rawValue

so far whenever the "test ads" banner from iAd appear it will carry a value of "0" (zero), it didn't mentioned in details on Developer resources.

your kind reply is greatly appreciated.

Thanking you guys in advanced.

best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn’t going to be as exciting as you’d hoped, and it isn’t really related to iAd.

`ADAdType` is just an enum, with possible values of `Banner` or `MediumRectangle`.  Enums can have an underlying raw representation type, and `ADAdType`’s is `Int`.  `.rawValue` gives you access to its underlying representation for a given enum value – for `.Banner` it’ll be `0`, for `.MediumRectangle` it’ll be `1`.